# How do I determine the failed/removed HDD in mdadm raid?

Tags: hard-drive, mdadm, smartctl

My current mdstat:

```
$ cat /proc/mdstat 
Personalities : [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid1] [raid10] 
md0 : active raid6 sde[8] sdh[4] sdg[1] sdd[6] sdb[5] sdc[7]
      9766914560 blocks super 1.2 level 6, 512k chunk, algorithm 2 [7/6] [UUUUU_U]

unused devices: <none>
```

Here is mdadm --detail:

```
$ sudo mdadm --detail /dev/md0
/dev/md0:
        Version : 1.2
  Creation Time : Fri Apr 26 21:52:21 2013
     Raid Level : raid6
     Array Size : 9766914560 (9314.46 GiB 10001.32 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 1953382912 (1862.89 GiB 2000.26 GB)
   Raid Devices : 7
  Total Devices : 6
    Persistence : Superblock is persistent

    Update Time : Tue Mar 28 15:19:34 2017
          State : clean, degraded 
 Active Devices : 6
Working Devices : 6
 Failed Devices : 0
  Spare Devices : 0

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 512K

           Name : server:0  (local to host server)
           UUID : 7dfb32ef:8454e49b:ec03ac98:cdb2e691
         Events : 34230

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       8       8       64        0      active sync   /dev/sde
       1       8       96        1      active sync   /dev/sdg
       4       8      112        2      active sync   /dev/sdh
       5       8       16        3      active sync   /dev/sdb
       6       8       48        4      active sync   /dev/sdd
      10       0        0       10      removed
       7       8       32        6      active sync   /dev/sdc
```

My questions are:

1. How am I supposed to figure out the removed HDD? Without tricks and guesses like subtracting the set of disks shown in mdadm output from  all available HDDs in my system (ls /dev/sd*), etc....
2. Why mdadm could remove the disk? Is it OK to re-add it, if I run smartctl tests and they finish successfully?

**UPDATE**
Correct answer is sdf. I found it by comparing set of disks shown in mdadm output and all disks in the system (sda - is boot disk with OS), but I still found such procedure too difficult.

Comment: Please show output of command `smartctl -a /dev/sdb`.

Comment: @MikhailKhirgiy https://pastebin.com/Z86hBnZA

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can run `mdadm --detail /dev/md0` to get the UUID of the RAID array, in your case it's "7dfb32ef:8454e49b:ec03ac98:cdb2e691".

Then run `mdadm --examine /dev/sda` and check what `Array UID` it belongs to.  If it's the same and sda is missing in the `mdadm --detail /dev/md0` output, then it's most likely that disk which was removed.

I can't answer on the reason for `mdadm` to remove the disk, other than that you should be able to find more information in `dmesg` and in `/var/log`.

If those places looks ok, and `SMART` says the disk is ok, then it should be safe to add it again.

I would recommend you to configure `mdadm --monitor` so it runs and monitors your RAID sets and emails you if anything happens.

Comment: Yes, seems it is the only reliable way to find removed disk

Answer (score 1):

The sequence of disks in raid array is important. You can see it in output of command `mdadm --detail /dev/md0`. In your example it is:

```
sde sdg sdh sdb sdd missed sdc
```

If a disk has died or unplugged then it still belongs​ the raid array. In your example the disk was removed from the raid array manually via mdadm command​. `smartctl` is a good program to show disk health. But this program can't help you if you didn't know what disk was in the array.

Comment: That's wrong.  /proc/mdstat lists 6 active disks, and includes a mentioning that a seventh disk is missing.  sdb is clearly listed as active in the `mdadm --detail` command.

Comment: Yes, you is right

Comment: I updated my answer